# How to create a line with many fields?

Tags: android, dynamic, field

I want create a line with many fields, like this:

[image: I wnat this]

Sempre que eu clicar em "Add line fields" deve-se criar uma linha abaixo da outra com os 3 campos.

Currently my code inserts only one EditText. code:

```
final List<EditText> newFields = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llAddNewFields);
    Button btnCreateField = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btCreateField);
    btnCreateField.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            MY_COUNT++;
            EditText et = CriaeditText(String.valueOf(MY_COUNT));
            newFields.add(et);
            ll.addView(telefones.get(newFields.size()-1), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));               
        }
    });
```

Method create EditText:

```
private EditText CriaeditText(String hint) {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setId(Integer.valueOf(hint));
    editText.setHint(hint);
    editText.setTag(hint);
    return editText;
}
```

To get the values ​​of only one EditText:

```
 private List getValuesDynamicField(LinearLayout l, List<EditText> li){
    String[] arrValues = null;
    List data = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < l.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        if (l.getChildAt(i).getVisibility() != View.GONE)
        {
            String p = li.get(i).getText().toString();
            if (!p.equals(""))
            {
                data.add(p);
            }
        }
    }
    return data;                
}
```

How to adapt my code to insert the 3 fields as I want?

Comment: Why cant you use a Table layout for this purpose?

Comment: I can use the table, but what I want is how to dynamically insert 1 line with 3 fields dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to dynamically add row with three edit texts,

First you add a Table layout to your layout xml file.add set its id as "tablelayout".Then in code,

```
 TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);

 TableRow tr = new TableRow(YourActivity.this);

 EditText edit1=new EditText(YourActivity.this);
 edit1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
 EditText edit2=new EditText(YourActivity.this);
 edit2.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
 EditText edit3=new EditText(YourActivity.this);
 edit3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

 tr.addView(edit1);
 tr.addView(edit2);
 tr.addView(edit3);

 tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }
```

Comment: And how do I get to the field values​​? Before in my code, I had an array of EditText and got the value traversing this array.  

The code to create the fields  
`List <EditText> Newfields <EditText> = new ArrayList () ....... CriaeditText EditText et = (String.valueOf (MY_COUNT));  
newFields.add (et);` ..........  
  
And to rescue the method I used `getValuesDynamicField (LinearLayout l List <EditText> li)`.  
  
Now this new case are three fields at once. How would I associate an array once the 3 fields to retrieve later?

Comment: You can get the value of first field like, String value=edit1.getText().toString(); Do the same with remaining fields

Comment: Yes, but i can create many fields. Can be 10 lines of 3 fields, because makes it easy to retrieve values ​​per line. According to the function that currently have **getValuesDynamicField** but it is only for one field, and my question is how to create an array to pass the values ​​for each line group with 3 fields.